# Spring - Accessing parameters of annotation in Advice

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have the following annotation:

```
public @interface Log {
    int id() default 0;
}
```

Now, I want to access the id field in an advice method. For example, if I call foo, then it's id (1) should get printed.

```
@Log(id = 1)
public void foo() {}
```

So far, I've got this :

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.skyfall.aspects.Log)")
    public void logPointcut(com.skyfall.aspects.Log log) {}

@Before("logPointcut(log))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint, com.skyfall.aspects.Log log) {
    System.out.println(log.id());
    }
```

However, I an error saying "when using @annotation(annotationtype(annotation field)) annotation field must be bound"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this, because you are using the pointcut with its binding form format where you use just the parameter name and the type of the annotation is taken from the `logBefore` method:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(log)")
public void logPointcut(com.skyfall.aspects.Log log) {}

@Before("logPointcut(log))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint, com.skyfall.aspects.Log log) {
    System.out.println(log.id());
}
```